# How to show message from custom function w/o using task pane or return value?

Tags: excel-addins, custom-functions-excel, javascript-api-for-office

Is it possible to show a message (just a warning the user can dismiss) from code in a custom function without using a task pane? (And without making it the return value of the function.) Something that shows up in the status bar, or a popup, etc.?

And obviously, if so, how do you do it?

(`Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` isn't available from the custom functions context, not even in the shared runtime.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reaching us. So far we don't support it. I'd recommend going to [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) and see if this feature has already been requested or if request a new feature. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Thanks. You've said "we". Are you a representative of Microsoft?